# How to adjust the CSS animation timing?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the CSS below that does a rotate and fade-in and it works just fine. The rotate/fade is timed just like I want it but I'd like a longer duration between the rotate/fade -- like 30s or so. If I increase duration, that slows the rotate/fade too much. How do I set the keyframes to retain the rotate/spin timing but allow 30s between the rotate/fade? I searched but couldn't find an applicable answer. Thank you very much.

```
@-webkit-keyframes SomeName {
0%   { opacity:0; -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); }
50%  { opacity:0; -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); }
75%  { opacity:1; -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
100% { opacity:1; -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}

#flipBox img.flippy {
-webkit-animation-name: SomeName;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

p.s. FYI: This is webkit only, hence the only prefix.

Comment: Here's a handy reference: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/14/the-guide-to-css-animation-principles-and-examples/

Comment: Seems there's no simple solution for this. Is there any requirements to dynamically change the duration? If not, maybe adjusting the percentage in `@keyframes` is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rrFLa/)

Use this code

```
animation:SomeName 5s;
-moz-animation:SomeName 5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:SomeName 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation:SomeName 5s; /* Opera */
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Sandeep. But I have no problem making my example work in equal portions, as you've shown with the colors in your demo -- but I want my fade/rotate to take 10s and then not loop again until 30s later. I can increase duration - but then the fade/rotate speed will not remain the same.